# SignalR eventually floods my application pool (causing lock up)

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I've been having this issue for quite a while now, where somehow the state of one of my SignalR clients (or many of them?) enters this behavior of switching to longPolling and then completely flooding my application pool.  There will be a lot of reconnects and start/stop polling requests.  It looks something like one of these two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

This eventually causes my entire web server to lock up since the application pool becomes full.

What might cause these scenarios?  Why does it fall back on to longPolling, and why does it end up flooding the server?

Comment: Once SignalR estabilishes a connection it will not switch to a different transport. If it cannot reconnect using the transport it originally used to connect to the server it will just disconnect. It seems like there is something going on on the client which opens multiple connections...

Comment: It may be caused by wrong .Net version - see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265445/signalr-always-downgrades-to-long-polling